# What is the proper postgresql index for listing all distinct json array values?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have the following query

```
select distinct c1::text 
from (select json_array_elements((value::jsonb -> 'boundaries')::json) as c1 from geoinfo) t1;
```

And I get this query plan:

```
                                             QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 HashAggregate  (cost=912918.87..912921.87 rows=200 width=32)
   Group Key: (t1.c1)::text
   ->  Subquery Scan on t1  (cost=1000.00..906769.25 rows=2459849 width=32)
         ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..869871.51 rows=2459849 width=32)
               Workers Planned: 2
               ->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..622886.61 rows=102493700 width=32)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on geoinfo  (cost=0.00..89919.37 rows=1024937 width=222)
```

There are ~500 rows returned from a table with 2.5 Million rows.

What index can I create that will cause this query to execute much faster?

I tried the somewhat obvious, and it didn't work:

```
# create index gin_boundaries_array on geoinfo using gin (json_array_elements((value::jsonb -> 'boundaries')::json));
ERROR:  set-returning functions are not allowed in index expressions
LINE 1: ... index gin_boundaries_array on geoinfo using gin (json_array...
```

Comment: I would consider not storing these as json(b) arrays, but real relational tables.

Comment: That looks like a house-keeping query.  Do you really run it often enough to care?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1000 on Bergi's comment. JSON is a *fantastic* interchange format. But for searchable storage? It's an edge-case that's become mainstream. Doesn't mean that it's always ill-advised, but when you start having to do `joins` against nested/embedded elements, spend a lot of mental bandwidth (and syntactic sugar) to get things done, etc., it's worth asking "is the convenience of stuffing things into JSON outweighed by the cost and hassle of seeing inside the objects, and getting things out?"

Specifically in Postgres, you *can* index JSON elements, but the planner *cannot* maintain useful statistics in the way that it can on full columns. (As I understand it, I haven't tested this out...I use JSON(B) for raw storage of JSON and search by other columns.)

As you may already know, Postgres has a lot of handy utilities for dealing with JSON. I have one JSONB field that I expand using `jsonb_to_recordset` and a `cross join`. If you're in the mood, it would be worth setting yourself up a test database. Unpack the JSON into a real table, and then try your queries against that. See for yourself if it's a better fit for your needs or not.